# Convert cin to argc argv input. New to using command line to pass values

Tags: c++, cin, argv, argc

I need to convert the cin to argc argv input style and have no idea how to go about it. this is the main body of my code where all of the input lays if I could get some help. All of this is in c++

This What I have been told "You need to use argc and agrv[] in your main function. So users can inputs information into your program when they run it. For instance, "yourprogram.exe -P 50"." Thank you in advance.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string userChoice = "";

    using std::string;
    int stop = 0;
    double pwm = 0;

    WritePWMfreq(46);

    cout << "PWM frequency set to: " << ReadPWMfreq() + 1 << "Hz" << endl;

    cout << "Enter 'P' to set the Duty Cycle for the PWM, 'A' to see the Analogue Port number \nor 'L' to set a target value for ADC0 port to match: " << endl;

    cin >> userChoice;

    int userPWM = 0;

    if (userChoice == "P" | userChoice == "p")
    {

        cout << "Please enter a duty cycle value between 1 and 100: " << endl;

        cin >> userPWM;

        if ((userPWM < 1) | (userPWM > 100))
        {
            cout << "That is outside of the possible range. Please try again. " << endl;

            return 0;

        }
        else

            WritePWM(userPWM);
        ReadPWM();

        return 0;

    }

    if (userChoice == "A" | userChoice == "a")
    {
        int userPort = 0;

        cout << "Please choose a port between 0 to 7 to find its value: " << endl;

        cin >> userPort;

        if ((userPort < 0) | (userPort > 7))
        {
            cout << "There is no port of this number. Please try again. " << endl;

            return 0;

        }
        else

            WriteADCPort(userPort);

        return 0;
    }

    if ((userChoice == "L") | (userChoice == "l"))
    {
        int i = 50;
        int userTarget = 0;

        cout << "Please enter a target value: " << endl;

        cin >> userTarget;

        cout << "The target value is: " << userTarget << endl;

        WritePWM(i);

        ReadPWM();
        ReadADCPort();

        if ((i <= 100) | (i >= 0) | (stop = 1))
        {
            while (ReadADCPort() <= userTarget)
            {
                WritePWM(i--);
                ReadPWM();
                ReadADCPort();

                pwm = ReadPWM();

                if (pwm == 1 | pwm == 0)
                {
                    stop = 1;
                }


            }
            while (ReadADCPort() >= userTarget)
            {
                WritePWM(i++);
                ReadPWM();
                ReadADCPort();

                pwm = ReadPWM();

                if (pwm == 1 | pwm == 0)
                {
                    stop = 1;
                }

            }

        }


    }
    else

        cout << "Invalid option. Please enter either 'A', 'P' or 'L'. " << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The program has to be able to be run by an auto tester and therefore needs to be able to be run in the command line. No idea how to start or how to use argv argc inputs

Comment: This is covered in most introductory material about C++.   `main()` accepts two arguments, an `int` named (by convention) `argc`  (argument count) and a `char **` named `argv`.    `argv` represents an array of strings, and `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.    So, change `main()` to accept those arguments, and then iterate over and check/interpret each string as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is just an array, so convert the values from the appropriate slots in the array. The first command line option is in `argv[1]`, the second is in `argv[2]`, `stoi` can be used to convert the strings to integers.

```
userChoice = argv[1];

userPWM = stoi(argv[2]);

userPort = stoi(argv[2]);

userTarget = stoi(argv[2]);
```

There's zero error checking in this code. You should at least check that the user has entered two values

```
if (argc < 3)
    cout << "No option specified" << endl;
```

Comment: Within `main()`, `argv` is a pointer to a pointer (i.e. a `char **`), not an array.   When an array is passed to any function, it is converted to a pointer  (unless that function explicitly accepts a reference or pointer to an array, which `main()` does not).  That passed pointer can be used syntactically *as if* it is an array, but it is not an array.